# new line (\n) is appending in between file path strings while I trying to read the file path location through argparse

Tags: python

I tried to read the file through a command line argument from `argparse` library. But `\n`(new line) is appending in between two paths(folder path and file path) of string while reading from command line arguments. Here is my code

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='modelling') #Description 
parser.add_argument('-f', '--filename', type=str, metavar='', required=True, help='data file name') # file reading 
parser.add_argument('-d', '--foldername', type=str, metavar='', required=True, help='data folder path') # Folder

args = parser.parse_args() # reading the arguments

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_path = args.foldername
    file_path = args.filename
    print("File path: {0}/{1}".format(folder_path, file_path))
```

```
python test.py -f 'something.txt' -d '/home/Documents/data/processed'
```

Output:

```
File Location:/home/Documents/data/processed 
/something.txt
```

But I want to get the output combined path like this: "/home/Documents/data/processed/something.txt"

Comment: That's strange.  It doesn't happen for me.  When I run your code in my PyCharm IDE on a Mac, it does the right thing, printing the path on a single line.  Same goes for running at the command line using exactly the command you show above.

Comment: The code you posted works as it should, arguments do not have a `\n` unless explicitly specified. Try running your program from the command line, the problem is likely caused by your IDE.

Comment: @treuss The code I posted here didn't work on Pycharm IDE on a Linux machine.  But it's working perfectly when the folder path is stripped,

Comment: The strip doesn't hurt but is also completely unnecessary. If pycharm passes the last argument with trailing newline character to argv, then this is a bug in pycharm or in your setup.

Comment: @treuss I am sure this is not an IDE problem because the same code is running smoothly on a Linux server where there is no IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `strip` your `string`s to fix this. Example:

```
folder_path = args.foldername.strip()
```

Depending on the IDE and console you're using, you may not get away with inserting an extra `\n` in `input` calls.

Comment: I expect that the value in the question is understanding why the problem is occurring rather than how to remove the newline after the fact.

Comment: Thanks, it's working, I am using Pycharm, and the program will run on a Linux machine without IDE @JustLearning

Comment: @cryptoFool As I said, the IDE and specific terminal/console one uses may treat EOF in different ways. More details are needed to face this.